# Bootstrap HTML form only sending last data entry

Tags: html, ajax, forms

My form somehow only seems to send the last data entry (user_feel).
It's my first time working with forms and I can't figure out why the other entries aren't sent with the rest of the form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>How was your day? (So far)</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='custom.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-8 offset-xl-2 py-5">
                <h1>Activity form</h1>
                <p class="lead">Please indicate what you've eaten and which social activities (if any) you've participated in.</p>
                <form id="activity-form" method="post" action="form.php">
                    <div class="messages"></div>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <br />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">What is your name? *</label>
                                    <input id="name" type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name *" required="required" data-error="Name is required.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="time">Which part of the day are you reporting on? *</label>
                                    <select id="time" name="current_time" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Please specify the time of day.">
                                        <option value="">Select the time of day</option>
                                        <option value="morning">Morning</option>
                                        <option value="afternoon">Afternoon</option>
                                        <option value="evening">Evening</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="feel">How do you feel? *</label>
                                    <p>Level three is the base level. It's where you don't feel especially good or bad, and consider yourself feeling 'neutral' compared to how you usually feel.</p>
                                    <select id="feel" name="user_feel" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Please specify how you feel.">
                                        <option value="">Select how you feel</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Save data">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="text-muted">
                                    <strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js" integrity="sha256-dHf/YjH1A4tewEsKUSmNnV05DDbfGN3g7NMq86xgGh8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="form.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I serialize the form and send it using ajax, the php script echo's out all key:value pairs it gained form the post. This is where i only get the user_feel selection, all other selections from the form seem to be ignored.

This is the JS file:

```
$(function () {

    // init the validator
    // validator files are included in the download package
    // otherwise download from http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator

    $('#activity-form').validator();


    // when the form is submitted
    $('#activity-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        // if the validator does not prevent form submit
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "form.php";

            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    // data = JSON object that contact.php returns

                    // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('#activity-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#activity-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

And this is the PHP script:

```
<?php
$okMessage = 'Your data has been submitted succesfully! Thanks a bunch!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{
    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');


    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $debug = "";
        $debug .= "$key: $value\n";
    }

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage."\r\n".$debug);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

It's based on the code from: https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form

Comment: We need to see the rest of your code.

Comment: Added the rest of the code.

Comment: Please post the request headers of the submit